# Limit involving the inverse beta regularized function

Tags: limits, special-functions, beta-function

Let $0<p<\frac{1}{2}$. I am looking for the limit:

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \left(\frac{t}{\frac{t}{I_{2 p}^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)}-2 \sqrt{t} \sqrt{\frac{1}{I_{2 p}^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)}-1}+1}\right)^{t+1}$$
where $I^{-1}_{(.)}(.,.)$ is the Inverse Regularized Beta Function.

Numerically the convergence is extremely fast:[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the $t+1$ exponent, the function will converge quite slowly. If you try extremely larges values of $t,$ you'll see the apparent asymptotes are illusory.

Note that $\frac1{I^{-1}_{2p}(t/2, 1/2)}$ seems to converge to $1$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ for $0 \leq p,\space p= 0.5$; that should help.

If that holds up, the limit will be $\frac1{e}$.

Comment: The function does converge extremely slowly as I surmised which you will note for large values (try t = 10^10, eg). The value of InverseBetaRegularized doesn't converge to 1 for all values as I hypothesized but for the case at hand the values all approach 1 very closely for large values of t. The values of the function sans the ^(1+t) are close to one another as t -> infinity. Then raising that to (1+t) for large values of t makes the whole thing terribly unstable numerically. Sorry couldn't be of more help.